# Postgresql Procedure Error - Record "old" has no field

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I'm using postgresql procedures and here is my code;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.title_last_procedure()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
        update
            "Titles"
        set "entryCount" = "entryCount" + 1,
            "lastInsertedDate" = date_trunc('day', (now() + interval '3 hours')),
            "lastInsertedTime" = now(),
            "entryTodayCount" = 
                (case 
                    when old."lastInsertedDate" != new."lastInsertedDate" then 1    -- If date different.
                    else "lastInsertedDate" + 1                                     -- If date same.
                end)
        where new."TitleId" = id;
        return new;
    end if;
    return null; 
END;
$function$
;
```

I have two tables **Entries** and **Titles**, and I want, when I inserted to data in **Entries**, it increase **lastInsertDate** in **Titles** table. Everything works fine. But If title new, no any lastInsertDate so "old" gives error becouse no any data.

```
when old."lastInsertedDate" != new."lastInsertedDate" then 1
```

> DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: record "old" has no field "lastInsertedDate"

How can I set lastInsertedDate if record is new records without get error? Or how can i check if no old."lastInsertedDate" ?

Comment: There is no `old` record for an INSERT - only a `new` record.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are true :) but It works normally. Only gets error for first record.

Comment: The case expression makes no sense for an insert trigger as there will never be an `old` record.

Comment: I solved thank you so much.
`when "lastInsertedDate" != date_trunc('day', (now() + interval '3 hours')) then 1`